# How do I create a User without asking them to set their password?

Tags: apex, integration, user

I'm developing a new integration between SFDC and an external system.
Almost everything is working fine, but I'm facing some issues when creating a new user.

For now, the main problem is when I create a new User by API. I set his password with `System.setPassword(userId, password);`, but the first time they log in it still ask them to reset their password, on the other hand, documentation says

> When the user logs in with this password, they are not prompted to create a new password.

Is there anything I could do to pass by this page?

Comment: Can you please explain the process of user creation? Are you trying to do Single Sign On with third party external system?

Comment: Well, I'm actually working with Node and using npm JSForce https://jsforce.github.io/ 
My goal is to return a login URL to the third System.  After looking up a while, I found this: https://naX.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=accessToken 
But it gives me the change password page.

Comment: Are you trying to log into Salesforce with external system's credential or vice versa?

Comment: Salesforce credentials. It does log in, I have no issues with that. The only problem is that I'm getting the reset password page.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.SetPassword()` is Working as it was Designed in Salesforce. It may redirect to the "Change Your Password" page for security reasons but users can just click on cancel. The system will login the user without any problem.

This happens because Password reset through Developer Console follows the password complexity set on Password Policies from the user's Profile.

Comment: I know I answered very late for this question. Probably It wont matter to you anymore but others who are stuck with this issue, may find this helpful. 

I just tested myself. It still does the same thing. For a new user, if we set password using System.SetPassword(), it still directs the users to change password first. but upon clicking on cancel button, they can start accessing their Org. Its just a best practice and recommended to change the password before users start using their Org.